# How do to speed up ordinary dataframe loop in python? vectorisation? multiprocess?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, vectorization

I have a simple piece of code.
Essentially, I want to speed up my loop that creates a dataframe using dataframes.
I haven't found an example and would appreciate anyones help.

```
df_new = []

for df_i in df:
   df_selected = df[df['good_value'] == df_i_list]
   df_new = pd.concat([df_new,df_selected])
```

Comment: your loop is empty, so it will take no time to execute. you cannot speed up 0.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This isn't valid Python code.

Comment: The series' "isin" method checks if an entry in the series is equal to one of multiple items at once.

Comment: The only heavy operation there is pd.concat, it should really be done only once.

Comment: @ljimc thanks, I'll revise that part

Comment: @ljmc I revised with your method, it computes in the same time as my approach :(

Comment: @MichaelButscher your method is 4x faster! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given your code does not work, this is the best I can come up with.

Start with a list of dataframes, then select the rows in your dataframes to another list and then concat in one step.

Since concat is the heavy operation, this makes sure you call it only once, which is how it's meant to be used.

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, ...]

sel = [df[df['column_to_filter'] == 'good_value'] for df in dfs]

df_new = pd.concat(sel)  # might be useful to add `ignore_index=True`
```

Answer (score 0):

df_new = df[df['good_value'].isin(df_i_list)]

The pd.concat is 4x slower than .isin()